# Dagger injection in Base Class is a good approach?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I have a `Car` class which extends `Vehicle` class, i will be injecting some properties in the vehicle class.
**Example**  **EDITED**

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    @Inject
    lateinit var default: Default
}

class Car @Inject constructor(): Vehicle() {

}
```

In my code everything works fine,

> But one thing i need to know is that how the dagger injects the
> properties in base class or its hierarchy?
>
> is this the proper way of
> injecting?

can anyone clarify this?

Comment: I think your `lateinit var` field will be uninitialized

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes ,it is not initialized.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i edited my example, i use constructor injection, it worked perfectly.

Comment: In general you shouldn't use field injection unless forced by some framework, constructor injection is otherwise always preferred.

Comment: @al3c if so how to inject those in the base class.

Comment: @Stack you can do smth like: `class Base(val dependency: Dependency)`, `class Car @Inject constructor(dependency: Dependency): Base(dependency)`

Comment: @GV_FiQst thank you for you suggestion, is the approach in my example is wrong ?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just not recommended. You can use it, and it will be working, but I agree with @al3c that constructor injection is better.

Comment: There is another question to ask. Is that Activity or Fragment? if so you have no other choice but to use field injection

Comment: @GV_FiQst it is not activity/fragment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But one thing i need to know is that how the dagger injects the properties in base class or its hierarchy?

For that you can look at the generated source files. In your case there will be something like that:

```java
class Car_Factory implements Factory<Car> {

  @Override
  public Car get() {
    return provideInstance(
      defaultProvider
    );
  }

  public static Car provideInstance(
    Provider<Default> defaultProvider
  ) {
    Car instance = new Car();

    Vehicle_MembersInjector.injectDefault(instance, defaultProvider.get()); // just instance.default = default here
    return instance;
  }
}
```

As you can see it will create your instance and then will access it's fields (as long as they are public and writable).

> is this the proper way of injecting?

It's not recommended way, as you're exposing the fields, which could be private (or protected), and you enabling someone else outside to modify, which violates encapsulation.

Therefore it's better to use constructor injection in this way:

```kotlin
abstract class Vehicle(protected val default: Default)

class Car @Inject constructor(default: Default) : Vehicle(default)
```

In this way Dagger will create your instance with already initialized fields, and won't be accessing them